# No exception upon insertion of document

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I am learning MongoDB. The thing that is confusing me right now is collections don't enforce the strict structure like RDBMS. I created a document with following parameters:

```
db.tempTable.insert({
    id: 1,
    name: umer
});
```

then I inserted:

```
db.tempTable.insert({
    "id":2,
    "name": "khan",
    "yolo":"todolo"
});
```

Both the queries were successful. I thought Mongo would raise an exception in the second insertion because the collection didn;t have the "YOLO" column in the  collection.

Why is that? Can we enforce the strict structure to avoid confusions while inserting in the table?

Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, [MongoDB is schemaless](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/119945109/why-schemaless). This means there is no strict schema. The only way you can raise an exception to ensure all documents have the same fields is at your code level, perhaps by using [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping)

Answer (score 0):

Like @hd says, mongodb is schemaless. But there is solutions to play with like [validators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document-validation/) that allow you to validate data before to insert them.

@example of new validator

```
db.runCommand( {
   collMod: "contacts",
   validator: { $or: [ { phone: { $exists: true } }, { email: { $exists: true } } ] },
   validationLevel: "moderate"
} )
```